# Custom Control check if resizing is started

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have created a custom `Control` called `Ellipse`. I'm able to resize, move, and paint this `Ellipse`. Now I'm trying to add undo/redo functionality for the resizing. The user can resize the control at the bottom right corner. At the moment the control prints hello as long as the cursor is positioned at the bottom right corner of the `Control`. But what I want is that when the user starts resizing (so leftmouse button is down and cursor is at the bottom right corner) hello is printed (only once). How to do this or is there a another (better) way to do it?

Ellipse.cs

```
class Ellipse : Control
{
    private Point mDown { get; set; }

    public Ellipse()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        this.ResizeRedraw = true;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        // Draw a black ellipse in the rectangle represented by the control.
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, Width, Height);

    }  

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        mDown = e.Location;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Call MyBase.OnMouseMove to activate the delegate. 
        base.OnMouseMove(e);


        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Location = new Point(e.X + Left - mDown.X, e.Y + Top - mDown.Y);
        }
    }

    /* Allow resizing at the bottom right corner */
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const int wmNcHitTest = 0x84;
        const int htBottomLeft = 16;
        const int htBottomRight = 17;

        if (m.Msg == wmNcHitTest)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
            int x = (int)(m.LParam.ToInt64() & 0xFFFF);
            int y = (int)((m.LParam.ToInt64() & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);
            Point pt = PointToClient(new Point(x, y));
            Size clientSize = ClientSize;
            if (pt.X >= clientSize.Width - 16 && pt.Y >= clientSize.Height - 16 && clientSize.Height >= 16)
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)(IsMirrored ? htBottomLeft : htBottomRight);
                return;
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try adding a couple more messages to check for the mouse going down in the non-client area and then another one for when the sizing was finished to complete the transaction:

```
private bool userResizing = false;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
  const int wmNcHitTest = 0x84;
  const int htBottomLeft = 16;
  const int htBottomRight = 17;
  const int WM_EXITSIZEMOVE = 0x232;
  const int WM_NCLBUTTONDWN = 0xA1;

  if (m.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDWN) {
    if (!userResizing) {
      userResizing = true;
      Console.WriteLine("Start Resizing");
    }
  } else if (m.Msg == WM_EXITSIZEMOVE) {
    if (userResizing) {
      userResizing = false;
      Console.WriteLine("Finish Resizing");
    }
  } else if (m.Msg == wmNcHitTest) {
    int x = (int)(m.LParam.ToInt64() & 0xFFFF);
    int y = (int)((m.LParam.ToInt64() & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);
    Point pt = PointToClient(new Point(x, y));
    Size clientSize = ClientSize;
    if (pt.X >= clientSize.Width - 16 && 
        pt.Y >= clientSize.Height - 16 &&
        clientSize.Height >= 16) {
      m.Result = (IntPtr)(IsMirrored ? htBottomLeft : htBottomRight);
      return;
    }
  }
  base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I get an error on the line where I want to add the `Control` to my `Panel`  `panel.Controls.Add(el);`. The error message is >Error creating window handle, is it because to many handles are created?

Comment: @Sybren I do not get that same error.  Too many handles?  How many ellipses are you creating?

Comment: Only creating one, don't know why the error pops up, I looked up what the error means and read about too many handles, but maybe it's something else, any idea?

Comment: @Sybren No idea based on the code you posted.  A handle error usually means you are doing something in the constructor `public Ellipse() { ... }` that you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: All you can see in the constructor code of `Ellipse` is what I'm doing, no more.

Comment: @Sybren I have the same code, and no errors.  There is something different in your implementation.  Start commenting out code until the error doesn't show up anymore, then start adding pieces back in until you find the culprit.

Comment: I will try to do that tommorow and I will get back to you then.

Comment: I found the culprit I forgot to add this line at the end of the method : `base.WndProc(ref m);`, it works as intended now, I will mark your answer as accepted.